# Root process suddenly uses gzip and takes up %75> CPU

Tags: system, process, top

I've been noticing late that my laptop will slow down suddenly, and the culprit is usually gzip being launched by a root process. This happens occassionally and I have no idea what's causing it. It really slows the desktop, it takes me a while to launch the terminal, find process ID and kill it. What's going on? Can I remove gzip? I don't know if this is helpful, but it might be something to do with logrotate, not sure how to proceed though.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
11561 root      20   0    4636   1464   1172 R  77.4  0.0   7:43.85 gzip        
   43 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.0  0.0   0:20.47 kswapd0     
  915 root      20   0  275884   4032   3624 S   0.5  0.1   0:08.27 accounts-d+ 
 1186 root      20   0  394560  48568  33388 S   0.5  0.6  92:25.27 Xorg        
11791 aj123     20   0   41800   3604   3036 R   0.5  0.0   0:00.01 top         
31916 aj123     20   0 3468324 698144  59860 S   0.5  8.7 129:06.56 firefox     
    1 root      20   0  187644   6992   2900 S   0.0  0.1  65:20.66 systemd     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.11 kthreadd    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:09.49 ksoftirqd/0 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   2:52.61 rcu_sched   
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh      
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.48 migration/0 
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.72 watchdog/0  
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.66 watchdog/1  
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:02.46 migration/1 
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:10.68 ksoftirqd/1
```

Comment: I'd guess it is related to logrotate.  These cron jobs usually run at the middle of the night so as to not interfere with interactive operations.  You said laptop and then desktop.  It could also be an operation like automatic backup that typically also runs at odd hours unless the machine is turned off.  If so, it will start shortly after the machine is powered on.  If it's backup you can change the settings to be more favorable to your work style.

Comment: I meant desktop as in the desktop environment becoming slow, didn't mean a desktop computer. I appreciate the advice, however I just checked and automatic backup seems off, what do you think I should do next?

Comment: I noticed Mozilla Thunderbird sometimes decides to compress emails and messages - for me this was the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Package gzip has priority, meaning it must always be installed for the system to work properly. Probably aptitude is therefore refusing to remove it.

Btw: Removing gzip is a really bad idea...

If you see gzip consuming a lot of CPU, that's because some other program is using it. If you want to do something about this, find out which program is using gzip, and change the program "if it is possible". To do this, use `pstree -apl` to see all processes with their parents, look for gzip and what its parents are, then check why they are calling to use gzip.

Comment: Would I have to wait for the next time my laptop becomes buggy, or is there a way for me to check after the fact?

Comment: You can check whenever gzip is pulling cpu